# Result of character(0) when trying to web scrape text

Tags: r, web-scraping, html-parsing, rvest

I'm attempting to automate scraping the practice words from this site https://www.livechatinc.com/typing-speed-test/#/ but get a result of 'character(o)'.

I read the url with read_html then use that for x in html_nodes() along with the css selector for the practice words and then read it with html_text, but I get character(0) every time.

No clue what I'm doing wrong, here is the code:

```
library('rvest')
url <- read_html("https://www.livechatinc.com/typing-speed-test/#/")

wbpg_html <- html_nodes(url,".test-prompt") 
wbpg_txt <- html_text(wbpg_html)

> wbpg_txt
 character(0)
```

I'd just like to get the practice words into r, find out how to automate it later.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What are the words seen on the webpage? I see a couple of words and some video.

Comment: @NelsonGon the words you are supposed type  or the "practice words" as I referenced them

Comment: Are they written in `html` or some other language? There is only one input "place" and it seems to be interactive. Might be less trivial to get with `html_nodes`.

Comment: The words aren't actually in the source code when you load the page but they are an element when you inspect them with google dev tools @NelsonGon

Comment: It looks like the words are loaded with React, a JavaScript framework, and so don't exist in the HTML until the JavaScript is run (which `read_html` doesn't do). So to scrape them you'd have to use a more heavy-duty scraper.

Answer (score 0):

The word list comes from this js file: https://cdn.livechatinc.com/gtt/app.3.8.min.js

You can try to regex out with R using:

```
e\\.exports=\\{words:\\[(.*?)\\]
```

I ran a quick test with python:

```
import requests, re

r = requests.get('https://cdn.livechatinc.com/gtt/app.3.8.min.js')
p = re.compile(r'e\.exports={words:\[(.*?)\]')
words = p.findall(r.text)
print(words)
```

With r

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
urlmatrix <- paste(readLines('https://cdn.livechatinc.com/gtt/app.3.8.min.js', warn=FALSE), 
                                collapse=" ", fileEncoding = "UTF-16") %>%
                                str_match(., 'e\\.exports=\\{words:\\[(.*?)\\]')
words <- strsplit(as.character(as.list(urlmatrix[,2])[[1]]), '","')
words[[1]][1] <- substring(words[[1]][1],2,nchar(words[[1]][1]))
words[[1]][length(words[[1]])] <- gsub('\\"', "", words[[1]][length(words[[1]])])
```